# Does QJsonValue differ strings of digits from integers?

Tags: qt, qjsonobject

When I parse json, is there any way to distinct this situations:

```
my_value = "123"
```

and

```
my_value = 123
```

?

Comment: Yes. You need to call `QJsonValue::type()` to get the type: `QJsonValue::String` or double `QJsonValue::Double` respectively.

Comment: Thank you @vahancho! You should have write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the type of JSON values. In order to get it, you need to call `QJsonValue::type()` function. In your case it will return either `QJsonValue::String` or `QJsonValue::Double` respectively.